# Стиль в Android при нажатии на NavigationView

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Добрый день.

Есть Android приложением, с меню на основе компонента NavigationView.
И вот при нажатии на любой пункт меню, и небольшом удержании, строка меню в виде анимации начинает подсвечиваться розовым цветом.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как называется в XML стилей атрибут отвечающий за этот цвет? Уже всю документацию просмотрел, множество параметров перепробовал, но найти нужный не удалось.

Comment: А `app:itemBackground` пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

Для цвета текста - вот это

```
// FOR NAVIGATION VIEW ITEM TEXT COLOR
    int[][] state = new int[][] {
//            (Цвет текста всех "включеных" элементов бокового меню )
//            (если этот массив не закоментировать, то остальные массивы работать не будут)
//          new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, // checked
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},  // pressed
            new int[]{}
    };

    int[] color = new int[]{
//            Color.GREEN,
            Color.parseColor("#724646"),
            Color.parseColor("#724646"),
            Color.parseColor("#724646")
    };

    ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(state, color);
```

Это - для иконок

```
    //FOR NAVIGATION VIEW ITEM ICON COLOR
    int[][] stateIcon = new int[][]{
//            (Цвет текста всех "включеных" элементов бокового меню )
//            (если этот массив не закоментировать, то остальные массивы работать не будут)
//            new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, // checked
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},  // pressed
            new int[]{}
    };

    int[] colorIcon = new int[]{
//            Color.GREEN,
            Color.parseColor("#724646"),
            Color.parseColor("#724646"),
            Color.parseColor("#724646")
    };
    ColorStateList csIcon = new ColorStateList(stateIcon, colorIcon);
```

Далее программно назначайте эти stateList-ы так:

```
navigationView.setItemTextColor(csl);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(csIcon);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/my_ripple"
    app:itemIconTint="#2196f3" // Цвет тени
    app:itemTextColor="#009688" // Цвет текста
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
```